# How to update jquery to v1.7.2 in drupal 6

Tags: jquery, drupal

I want to use a jquery plugin that need jquery v1.7.2 in my drupal v6 website.
i replace drupal's jquery with this version of jquery but, some part of website don't work with that. for example views seems have problem.
is threre a way to upgrade jquery in drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **[Using Newer Versions of jQuery](http://drupal.org/node/1058168)** in official Drupal page.

Answer (score 2):

you can link jquery 1.7 using your theme's .info file (see http://drupal.org/node/171205 under scripts section). If you use official jquery it will be accessible using $. Drupal's jquery can be accessed using jQuery cause it is using .noConflict (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

so basicly put new jquery to .info file of your theme and it will be accessible using $ and all drupal will still use old jquery using "jQuery" function.

i work mainly with drupal 7 but as i know it should work with D6 also.